# Can't acess file I've just created on script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a file with my script and move it just after the creation. The code that creates the file:

```
fh.seek(0)
with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(fh, f)
    f.close()
```

And the command that moves it just after:

```
os.system('mv caderneta.db caderneta.db ' + PATH_TO_DB_FOLDER)
```

The thing is, if the execution ends just after the first part of the code, the file is created, but if the os command is on the code it doesn't create the file and the command shows an error.
I've tried executing it on a shell script file after the execution of the python file but it still doesn't working, showing the same problems.

Comment: i'm not sure but try `shutil.copyfileobj(fh, f.write())`

Comment: `'mv caderneta.db caderneta.db ' + PATH_TO_DB_FOLDER` Why did you put the filename twice in that command?

Comment: @tomatoeshift shows: TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Comment: You don't need `f.close()`, that's done automatically by `with`.

Comment: @JohnGordon I think it is in fact wrong, but I don't think it has anything to do with my problem

Comment: @Barmar I wrote it trying to make it work

Comment: oh, try without the parentheses then `shutil.copyfileobj(fh, f.write)`

Comment: @tomatoeshift shows this error: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'write'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra argument to the `mv` command. It should just be:

```
os.system('mv caderneta.db ' + PATH_TO_DB_FOLDER)
```

But you shouldn't use `os.system()` for this, use `shutil.move()`

```
shutil.move('caderneta.db', PATH_TO_DB_FOLDER)
```

Comment: No, you should do it outside the scope, so that the file will be closed.